# Struggling with Top Alignment / Vertical Alignment with Tabular

Tags: tables, makecell

I am struggling to align the content of the left column to the top of the tabular cell. I have tried using the `\begin{tabular}[t]{|l|l|}`, as most other posts have suggested, but have had no luck in fixing it. Please assist.

Here is my code for reference:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|l|l|}
    \hline
       \textbf{Fact Finding Heading}  &  \textbf{Stakeholder issues} \\\hline
        Materials / Supply Chain / Manufacturing  & \makecell[l]{1. \\ 2. \\ 3. \\} \\\hline
        Environment & \makecell[l]{1. \\ 2. \\ 3. \\} \\\hline
        Society & \makecell[l]{1. \\ 2. \\ 3. \\} \\\hline
        Energy & \makecell[l]{1. \\ 2. \\ } \\\hline
        Regulations & \makecell[l]{1. \\ 2. \\ } \\\hline
        Economy & \makecell[l]{1. \\ 2. \\ } \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thanks

Here is the output for reference. (I want the left column's text to be at the top left)

[image: Output with current code (I want the left column's text to be at the top left)]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! // A suggestion: please add the preamble and the \begin{document} and \end{document} statements, i.e. make it easy for people here to copy and compile your code. // I also suggest to have a closer look at the makecell manual, unless you did: https://ctan.org/pkg/makecell?lang=en , and check out Tables at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX // Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `\makecell[tl]` instead of `\makecell[l]` should result in the expected output. However, I personally would use a customized `enumerate`environment inside of each cell of the second column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem as you need to `t`op-align the right column entries. Think of it as setting the anchor for the cells. Below I've adjusted the aesthetics using [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), but the principle remains the same even if you don't end up using that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l l }
  \toprule
  \textbf{Fact Finding Heading} & \textbf{Stakeholder issues}              \\
  \midrule
  \makecell[lt]{Materials / \\ 
    Supply Chain / \\
    Manufacturing}                         & \makecell[lt]{1. \\ 2. \\ 3.} \\
  \addlinespace
  Environment                              & \makecell[lt]{1. \\ 2. \\ 3.} \\
  \addlinespace
  Society                                  & \makecell[lt]{1. \\ 2. \\ 3.} \\
  \addlinespace
  Energy                                   & \makecell[lt]{1. \\ 2.}       \\
  \addlinespace
  Regulations                              & \makecell[lt]{1. \\ 2.}       \\
  \addlinespace
  Economy                                  & \makecell[lt]{1. \\ 2.}       \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using a combination of `tabularx`, `booktabs` and `enumitem`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label*=\arabic*.,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  nosep,
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
                  after=\end{minipage}}



\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{4.25cm}X}
    \toprule
       Fact Finding Heading  &  Stakeholder issues \\
    \midrule
        Materials / Supply Chain / Manufacturing  & \begin{tabenum}
                        \item A longer line of text that gets automatically broken over multiple lines.
                        \item text
                        \item text
                      \end{tabenum} \\ \addlinespace
        Environment & \begin{tabenum}
                        \item text
                        \item text
                        \item text
                      \end{tabenum}\\ \addlinespace
        Society & \begin{tabenum}
                        \item text
                        \item text
                        \item text
                      \end{tabenum} \\ \addlinespace
        Energy & \begin{tabenum}
                        \item text
                        \item text
                      \end{tabenum} \\ \addlinespace
        Regulations & \begin{tabenum}
                        \item text
                        \item text
                      \end{tabenum} \\ \addlinespace
        Economy & \begin{tabenum}
                        \item text
                        \item text
                      \end{tabenum} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried adding the `\makecell[lt]{}` to the left column's items, and it still didn't work, but after I copied your code it did! Will try to find out what the issue was. 

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It’s easy peasy with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package: you don't need `\makecell` command and `makecell` package any more.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}[t]{|l|l|}
    \hline
       \textbf{Fact Finding Heading}  &  \textbf{Stakeholder issues} \\\hline
        Materials / Supply Chain / Manufacturing  & {1. Text\\ 2. Text\\ 3. Text} \\\hline
        Environment & {1. Text\\ 2. Text\\ 3. Text} \\\hline
        Society     & {1. Text\\ 2. Text\\ 3. Text} \\\hline
        Energy      & {1. Text\\ 2. Text} \\\hline
        Regulations & {1. Text\\ 2. Text} \\\hline
        Economy     & {1. Text\\ 2. Text} \\\hline
    \end{tblr}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]